# wordpress multisite duplicator plugin clon to localhost(xampp) but image not show

Tags: multisite, localhost, xampp

I duplicate my wordpress network site (with duplicator pro plugin) to my localhost every things is good except image not show !!

when i right click on image to find the image path ! the path is somthing like

```
http://localhost\C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-includes\images\x.jpg
```

you cas see in image :[image: File path problme]

and when i try to access the path :`http://localhost\C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-includes\images\x.jpg`its not posible and I recive 403 error(access denid) but the image existe and i can access them with `http://localhost/wp-includes/images/x.jpg` address!!!!

how i fix this problem !!

Answer (score -1):

I change `Upload Path` From setting and problem solved